# Firebase Gluon Mobile

Tags: javafx, javafxports, gluon, gluon-mobile

If I wanted to use a library such as firebase which has android and ios SDK's, for the iOS port, how would I approach writing the code and adding it to my Gluon Mobile project? Also, for use on android, would I just need to add the firebase libraries to the gradle build and write the custom code for it?

Comment: please refer this [link](https://console.firebase.google.com/)